# Visual Studio doesn't debug after reaches end of file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

So for some reason my visual studio will not debug the next line after I exit a function.  So to explain this better I have the following code:

File1.cs

```
public bool ReturnSomething(){
    var test = true;
    var test2 = MyOtherFunction(test);
    var test3 = false;
}
```

File2.cs

```
public bool MyOtherFunction(bool test){
    var test2 = true;
    return test2;
}
```

As you can see the code above is very simple and straight forward.  So I will put a breakpoint on function ReturnSomething on variable test and I will run my project.  The breakpoint will hit.  I will hit F10 to go to next line which is `var test2 = MyOtherFunction(test);`  There I will hit F11 to step into function.  Then I will hit F10 to go to next line, then F10 again to exit out the function and here is the problem, it should go back to `var test3 = false;` however it doesn't, it just continues running off the rest of the code as if I just hit F5.  If I were to put a breakpoint on `var test3 = false;` then it would work.

Is this a setting of some sort that I have flipped or a bug?  I can't figure this out and its driving me nuts.

Comment: just click shift+F11 to step out of the method to the calling method instead of clicking on F10 - let me know if that support your problem and I'll add it as answer for others as well.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: @DeJaVo That is a workaround, not a solution.  I really want to get to the bottom of the problem.  Thanks for the workaround though.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side - do you have any exceptions? if not, please turn on exception from debug -> exceptions : check C++ exception and common language runtime exceptions.